# How can I see the number of maximum open files in PHP?

Tags: php, ulimit, fpm, wp-cli, setrlimit

With PHP I'm running into `failed to open stream: Too many open files` errors, thru wp-cli as well as through fpm-php.

I've adapted things like fpm's `rlimit` and `ulimit` on the command line. Now it would be really nice if I can see the maximum number of files a script can open without running the (slow) code.

How can I see the number of file I can open, from PHP itself?

I know I can look at configuration files, but I want to see the actual number that the current script has available so that I can adapt configuration files and see which change actually makes sense.

Unfortunately `phpinfo()` doesn't show this number.

If there's a shell command that shows this number, this would be good enough of course, as I could just `exec` that.

Comment: In /etc/security/limits.conf : not sure

Comment: on server debian you can go to also to

/etc/php/php7.xx/fpm/pool.d/www.conf   find "rlimit_files" then restart the server

Comment: Maximum available file descriptors for a PHP-script seems to be near `posix_getrlimit()['soft_openfiles']` (well, for Linux or POSIX systems), though minus a small though *varying* number of file descriptors (varies per environment, maybe because of files opened internally by PHP or parent processes?). Number of file descriptors in use, you could get by using result of `count(get_resources('stream'))` inside a script.

Comment: To correct my previous comment: the underscore in 'soft_openfiles' needs to be a space.

Comment: see `rlimit_files` in https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php
see also https://forum.hestiacp.com/t/too-many-open-files-despite-config-adjustments/8858/44?u=xeruf

Answer (score 1):

In php, before the execution, try this

```
exec('ulimit -S -n 2048');
```

Comment: This is useful but it doesn't show me the number of maximum open files. In order to avoid adding an extra `exec` to every script, I have to find out which configuration file to change to get the desired effect.